# Android WebView doesn't show image

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have an html file locally with local images. I'm trying to display it using

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(contentPath, content, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

where contentPath is the file path and the content is the actual html.
It is showing the html fine but the problem is I have images inside it that don't show. an example is

```
<img src="images/philippines-map.png" class="full_page_image" alt="full page image for Philippines map" style="max-width:100%">
```

I checked and the location is right. Instead of the image it is showing a box with the alt text inside it. Anyone knows what's going on?

here are the variables initiation code

```
contentPath = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + pageFolderName + "/" + pageName;
```

content is initiated by

```
StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(contentPath)), "ISO-8859-1"));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileData.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        reader.close();

        content = fileData.toString();
```

Comment: What is exactly the path in contentPath?

Comment: `contentPath is the file path and the content is the actual html`. Why are you using this construction?

Comment: Thank you guys. I tried it with both /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/folder/page /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/folder/ Where the location of images is /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/folder/images

Comment: The reason I'm using this way is because I have the html in a file locally (the images as well) I tried loadUrl using the path but it doesn't work. What did you have in mind greenapps?

Comment: `contentPath is the file path and the content is the actual html`does not match `I have the html in a file locally`.

Comment: It does, contentPath is the actual file path that I have locally and content is the actual html that I read from the file. I also mentioned that "I have an html file locally with local images"

Comment: Why would you mention that? And about which file are we talking here? Are there two html files in your problem?

Comment: `I tried it with both /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/folder/page `. Ok. But how? Please put that in your code so we can see how you tried.

Comment: I was answering your first question. contentPath is a string and I tried once to pass the first option and once to pass the second option as the value of contentPath.

Comment: There is only one html file. The user downloaded it and it is located locally at /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/folder/page where page is the html file. The image is also located locally. It is placed in /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/folder/images/philippines-map.png

Comment: Yes. we know that already long time. Why are you repeating yourself? This brings nothing. You should show us the code where you initiate `contentPath, content`. You should show us how you use that path. I asked that before.

Comment: I added the initiation code

Comment: Change `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(contentPath, content, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);` to `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://" + contentPath, content, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);`.

Comment: :) I just got that now myself and was about to post a response so other people know when I saw your comment. Thanks for helping out. If you want you can post a response and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(contentPath, content, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);` to `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://" + contentPath, content, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);`.

Answer (score 0):

In Android , file names and extenstions are case sensitive .
Check both file name and extenstion of your image are lower case .